# Why are people voting to close this question?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question

[What is the best way to use inheritance with ORMs?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/160473/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-inheritance-with-orms)

In my view, this is a perfectly appropriate question for Programmers.SE that can yield an objective, constructive answer.

Do people think that it would be more appropriate for Stackoverflow? Were people expecting code samples?

Answer (score 7):

Preface: I did not vote to close this question... :)

Sometimes using the word "best" in the title or main question will start a question down the slippery slope to closure.  What does "best" mean?  I don't know and the question doesn't help define it.

I think pdr's edits helped a great deal.  Hopefully the OP can add to the edits.

As far as being appropriate for our site, I think it is. It's a white board question that isn't looking for an implementation answer.

Answer (score 1):

It will likely yield an answer per ORM.  The OP did mention Entity and Django in the question, but the net is cast quite wide overall, since he's thinking of it in terms of the database itself still.

For example, Django has a [built-in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) way to do model inheritance - you never had to touch the foreign keys yourself.  But even if other frameworks also have their own ways, it isn't necessarily going to work the same as Django.